# Casting date from string spark

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having a Date in my dataframe in String Datatype with format - `dd/MM/yyyy` as below:

[image]

When I am trying to convert the string to date format, all the functions are returning null values.

Looking to convert the datatype to `DateType`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Use text formatting instead

Comment: Will keep in mind from next post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your date strings contain quotes, you need to remove them, using for example `regexp_replace`, before calling `to_date`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("'31-12-2021'",), ("'30-11-2021'",), ("'01-01-2022'",)], ["Birth_Date"])

df = df.withColumn(
    "Birth_Date",
    F.to_date(F.regexp_replace("Birth_Date", "'", ""), "dd-MM-yyyy")
)

df.show()
#+----------+
#|Birth_Date|
#+----------+
#|2021-12-31|
#|2021-11-30|
#|2022-01-01|
#+----------+
```

Comment: Yup the field contained quotes.. thanks for help.